# Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку.

````
    require_once 'getRecipes.php';
    require_once 'countIngridients.php';

    if($_POST['recipe']!="") {
        $recipes=getRecipe();
        $newRecipe = array("id" => uniqid(), "recipe" => $_POST['recipe']);
        array_push($recipes, $newRecipe);
        file_put_contents('../../data/recipes.txt', json_encode($recipes, true));
        // header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']);
        $recipes = getRecipe();
        $outpup = [];
        foreach ($recipes as $key=>$value) {
            $value['count'] = countIngridients($value["id"]);
            array_push($outpup, $value);
        }
        echo json_encode($outpup);
    }```

Notice: Undefined index: recipe in /home/user_7/html/LabWeb7/lib/php/putRecipe.php on line 5
````

Comment: Уведомление: неизвестный индекс xxx в файле yyy на строке zzz. Обращайтесь поработаю гуглтранслейтом за вас

Comment: У меня на ноуте не выдаёт такой ошибки, а на другом пк вылезает это.

Comment: Возможно у Вас на ноуте отключен показ предупреждений и ошибок.

Comment: Ошибка говорит что в массиве $_POST нету поля 'recipe', перед `$newRecipe = ...;` проверь наличие полей через `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Проверил. Ничего не выводит. Есть ещё идеи?

Comment: Если ничего не выводит, значит ничего нет. Отладка в помощь.

Comment: Ну так ошибка и возникает, потому что такого индекса нет. Замените проверку `$_POST['recipe']!=""` на `!empty($_POST['recipe'])` или `isset($_POST['recipe'])`, например.

Comment: ```
if($_POST['recipe']!="") {
        $recipes=getRecipe();
        print_r($_POST);                                                                                                              
        $newRecipe = array("id" => uniqid(), "recipe" => $_POST['recipe']);
        array_push($recipes, $newRecipe);```                                                                                                               Я ведь туда принт вставил?

Comment: если заменить на !emty, то выдаёт следующие: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting '(' in /home/user_7/html/LabWeb7/lib/php/putRecipe.php on line 5

Comment: ```if(!empty($_POST['recipe'])) {```

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо тебе огромное, друг.